# Kusto query language split @ character and take last item

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

If I have a string for example:
"this.is.a.string.and.I.need.the.last.part"
I am trying to get the last part of the string after the last ".", which in this case is "part"
How to I achieve this?
One way I tried was to split the string on ".", I get a array back, but then I don't know how to retrieve the last item in the array.

```
| extend ToSplitstring = split("this.is.a.string.and.I.need.the.last.part", ".")
```

gives me:

```
["this", "is","a","string","and","I","need","the","last", "part"]
```

and a second try I have tried this:

```
| extend ToSubstring = substring(myString, lastindexof(myString, ".")+1)
```

but Kusto do not have a function of lastindexof.

Anyone with tips?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can access the last member of the array using a negative index `-1`.

e.g. this:

`print split("this.is.a.string.and.I.need.the.last.part", ".")[-1]`

returns a single table, with a single column and a single record, with the value `part`

Comment: That easy, seriously. Now I feel bad. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below, and feel free to change it to meet your need:

```
let lastIndexof = (input:string, lookup: string) {
    indexof(input, lookup, 0, -1, countof(input,lookup))
};
your_table_name 
| extend ToSubstring = substring("this.is.a.string.and.I.need.the.last.part", lastIndexof("this.is.a.string.and.I.need.the.last.part", ".")+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `reverse()` function:

```
print reverse(split(reverse("this.is.a.string.and.I.need.the.last.part"), ".")[0])
```